# How to use "\dt" in cursor.execute() to get the tables in PostgreSQL? (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, dbtable

In Django, I'm trying to use **`\dt`** in **`cursor.execute()`** to get the tables in PostgreSQL as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection

def test(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''\dt''') # Here
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

But, I got the error below:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "\"
> LINE 1: \dt

So, I replaced **`cursor.execute('''\dt''')`** with **`cursor.execute('''\\dt''')`** as shown below:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection

def test(request):
    # ...    
    cursor.execute('''\\dt''') # Here
    # ...    
    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

But, I still got the error below:

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "\"
> LINE 1: \dt

So, how do I use **`\dt`** in `cursor.execute()` to get the tables in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2):

You can list the tables using plain SQL, without the need of psql.

```
cursor.execute('''
select *
from pg_catalog.pg_tables
where schemaname = '<your_schema_name>';
''')
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot to use `\dt` command as postgresql query. `\dt` is client side `psql` command. PostgreSQL can process just SQL commands (like `SELECT`,`INSERT`, `ALTER`, ...).

But there is some way:

1. run `psql` with parameter `-E`. That means *echo all*,
2. run selected backslash command (like `\dt`)
3. psql prints the result (and the SQL query generated for getting the result)
4. execute from Django this query